# A method to create a not-decreasing and not-increasing

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This morning I have explained the monotonous sequences $\{a_n\}$ for my students, but I have had the difficulty of write some simple examples of not-decreasing $a_{n+1}/a_n\geq 1$ and not-increasing sequences $a_{n+1}/a_n\leq 1$.

How to quickly create examples of not decreasing or not increasing monotonous sequences? Is there a specific criterion or method for to create examples?

Comment: $\sin(n)$ is not increasing and not decreasing.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for sequences that are monotonic but not strictly monotonic?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes, exactly. Thank you very much for to have understood my question. Please, can you edit my bad technical english language?

Comment: Take a sequence ${a_n}$ of non-negative terms with some strings of 0's in it. Then ${s_n}$ = the sum of the first n terms of ${a_n}$ will be monotonic but not strictly so.

Comment: How about $a_n=\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor$? -- Btw, $a_{n+1}/a_n\le 1$ would also allow *any* sequence with alternating signs

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you very much. But my students belong to an high school. Is this my problem and I can not to write hard examples.

Comment: @Paul Thank you also to you. See the previous my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some easy examples of nondecreasing monotonic sequences

- The constant sequence:
  $$1,1,1,1,1,1,1...$$
  Explicit forumula $a_n = 1$.
- The integers repeated once each: 
  $$1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,...$$
  Explicit formula: $a_n = \lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor$
- The partial decimal expansions of $1/27$: 
  $$0, 0.03, 0.037, 0.037, 0.03703, ...$$
  Explicit formula: $a_n = 10^{-n}\lfloor10^n/27\rfloor$
- The Fibonacci sequence, where the first two terms are $1$ and the remaining terms are the sum of the two previous: 
  $$1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55 ...$$
  Explicit formula: $a_n = \lfloor \phi^n/\sqrt{5}\rceil$, where $\phi = (1+\sqrt{5})/2$ is the golden ratio and $\lfloor x\rceil$ is the nearest integer function.
- The number of primes less than $n$:
  $$0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, ...$$
  Explicit formula: I'd just stick with the primary definition for this one, as it's simple enough to understand why it's not strictly increasing.*

For nonincreasing monotonic sequences, the reciprocals of the above sequences as well as their negations work. I'm having trouble thinking of natural nonincreasing monotonic sequence, though.

*If you must know, it's $a_n =\lceil R(n) - \sum_\rho R(n^\rho)\rceil$, where $R$ is the [Riemann $R$ function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannPrimeCountingFunction.html) and the sum runs over all complex roots of the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you add also nonincreasing examples and the general term of the sequences? I have had the same problem this morning. The students want everything right now. Always thank you and of course I appreciate your answer.

Comment: @Sebastiano The general terms of the Fibonacci sequence and especially the prime counting function may be beyond high school algebra, so those sequences should just be explained. The others are $1$, $2\lfloor n/2\rfloor$, and $\lfloor 10^n/27\rfloor/10^n$.

Comment: I assure you with all my heart that Italian high school is not what you think. You can't even imagine my effort, my effort and my concern about elementary algebraic passages.

Comment: @Sebastiano Slight correction: the general term of the second sequence is $\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor$.

Comment: Can you edit your accepted answer putting the general term near? Hence the examples born to experience :o). Thank you very much.